# What's the use of a callback function in PHP?

Tags: php, callback, synchronous

I'm in the process of learning PHP, and the concept of callback functions have me slightly confused. I understand that there are synchronous and asynchronous callbacks and that the common callback in PHP is synchronous. I have read through a lot of information regarding this topic, but I'm none the wiser still.

How is this:

```
function string($string, $callback) {
    $results = array(
        'upper' => strtoupper($string),
        'lower' => strtolower($string)
    );

    if(is_callable($callback)) {
        call_user_func($callback, $results);
    }
}

string('Danny', function($name) { 
    echo $name['upper']; 
    }
);
```

Different or better than this:

```
function string($string, $case) {
    $options = [
        'upper' => strtoupper($string),
        'lower' => strtolower($string)
    ];

    echo $options[$case];
}

string('Danny', 'upper');
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example with a callback you could easily pass a different function without changing the original code:

```
<?php

function string($string, $callback) {
    $results = array(
        'upper' => strtoupper($string),
        'lower' => strtolower($string)
    );

    if(is_callable($callback)) {
        call_user_func($callback, $results);
    }
}

string('Danny', function($name) { 
    echo $name['upper']; 
    }
);

string('Danny', function($name) { 
    echo 'Mr.'.$name['upper']; 
    }
);

string('Danny', function($name) { 
    echo 'Mrs.'.$name['upper']; 
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a typical example where the callback is better than the direct value:

```
function intricateProcessToCalculateDefault() {
   //Takes 3 seconds
}

function valueOrDefault($value, $default = null) {
    if ($value === null) {
        if (is_callable($default)) {
           return $default();
        }
        return $default;
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Now consider these two examples:

```
$valueToUse = valueOrDefault(
                  $_GET["parameterWithFallback"] ?? null, 
                  intricateProcessToCalculateDefault()
              );

// or 

$valueToUse = valueOrDefault(
                 $_GET["parameterWithFallback"] ?? null, 
                 function () { return intricateProcessToCalculateDefault(); }
              );
```

Now here's the thing. If you don't pass `parameterWithCallback` this will take 3 seconds either way. However if you do then `intricateProcessToCalculateDefault` will never be called if passed as a callback and will therefore save you time.

In your case, since the function code is ran in either case, there's no benefit.

PHP is mostly synchronous so there's no easy way to get asynchronous functions. Some libraries do offer them but that's usually tied with calling a shell executable or something similar.

Another use case is for [inversion for control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control). There are many generic algorithms which can be implemented with a "placeholder" for user code for. [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) is such an example.

```
$array = [ "string1", "sting2" ];
$action = "upper";
array_map(function ($value) use ($action) {
    return ucfirst(strtolower($value));
}, $array);
```

In this case control is inverted. A PHP function is calling your function instead of the other way around.

Comment: I understand your example. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but a function is being called to decide whether to return a value if one is present or to call for another function to calculate a default. Is it not just as efficient to settle that with an if statement with an early return at the beginning of the intricateProcessToCalculateDefault function? That would mean one function call no matter the situation, instead of two in the case of a missing value. Perhaps I'm not understanding the advantages of such modularity yet.

Comment: Efficiency-wise it's the same perhaps it's not the best example.